# Where can I find an English version of this paper by Gel'fand and Raikov?

Tags: reference-request, representation-theory, operator-algebras

It is titled 'Irreducible unitary representations of locally bicompact groups' and the original version is in Russian. Google scholar shows it has been translated into English and once pubulished in Amer. Math. Transl, 1964.

However, it does not give link to this journal. So I wonder whether some of you have a version of this paper or have access to it.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a [link](http://books.google.de/books?id=V1cPl3F7POIC&pg=PA1&lpg=PA1&dq=%22Irreducible%20unitary%20representations%20of%20locally%20bicompact%20groups%22&source=bl&ots=uE7EgdOmws&sig=f2RApdQ_AFXbix0qn0mDu8BGb5A&hl=de&sa=X&ei=ixw9T57WM83xsgbUv824BA&ved=0CFEQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=%22Irreducible%20unitary%20representations%20of%20locally%20bicompact%20groups%22&f=false) to the Google Books page.

Comment: WoW! Great, how do you find this one?! Thanks very much!